# Template helper and session based event

Tags: javascript, css, meteor

This Meteor client code tries to apply a css class to selected `li` when user invokes `click .list-item` event.  The problem is that the `li` to style is produced after the event is invoked so there is no reference to it at that time.

But I need the template to render the new data from the 'list' session then apply the styling. How can that be done? Thanks

```
Template.checks.helpers({
  'values': function() {

    //has the array of items for the template helpers
    return Session.get('list'); 
  }
});

Template.checks.events({
  'click .list-item': function() {

   //modifies Session 'list'
    utility.setList(); 

   //Applies the styling to certain list items.
    utility.checksFiltering($('input.check-filter').val());
  }
});
```

Comment: Rather than using jQuery, you could add an `isChecked` boolean to the relevant items inside of the list array. Then you could use that value directly in your template.

Comment: @DavidWeldon The jQuery is there only to grab some user input which is used as an argument  to the function that adds a class for styling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the checksFiltering happen after all currently queued tasks have been performed:

```
Meteor.defer( function() {
    utility.checksFiltering($('input.check-filter').val());
});
```

This will probably work, but not if setList() waits for stuff that schedules new Tracker events, for example, a new subscription. In that case you need to make the call to checkFiltering() dependent on some ready() callback in setList().